# Teams of users rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I need to create teams of users. A user belongs to a team (only one team) a team has many users. I can't figure out how to get a user to be able to create, join, and leave a team. Below is what I have so far, but I'm sure I'm doing something terribly (and "newby" wrong).

User Model:

```
belongs_to :teams, dependent: :destroy

def team_member?(team)
    team_relationships.find_by_team_id(team.id)
end

def join!(team)
    team_relationships.create!(team_id: team.id)
end  

def unjoin!(team)
    team_relationships.find_by_team_id(team.id).destroy
end
```

team model

```
has_many :users, through: :team_relationships, dependent: :destroy

attr_accessible :team_name, :team_id

validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :team_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

default_scope order: 'teams.created_at DESC'
```

team_relationship model

```
attr_accessible :team_id

belongs_to :team
belongs_to :user

validates :team_id, presence: true
```

routes:

```
  resources :teams do
    member do
      get 'join'
      get 'leave'
    end
  end
```

teams_controller:

```
def join
  @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, @team.id)
  redirect_to @user
end

def leave
  @team = Team.find params[:id]
  current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, nil)
  redirect_to @user
end
```

_join_team.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.team_relationships.build(team_id: @team_id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :team_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Join", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_unjoin_team.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.team_relationships.find_by_team_id(@team_id),
         html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Leave Team", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

If you can't tell I was trying to adapt some of what's in Hartl's tutorial for this purpose. What am I doing wrong?

I believe I have gotten the models figured out, but now I'm not sure how to get a user to create a team, destroy a team, join a team, or leave a team. What do I have to do in the models, controllers, and views to make it happen?

Comment: Can you post the code for the User model?

Comment: It's at the top just not indented properly ;)

Comment: @SteaveQ is team_relationships ? a middle assiciation model or you wanted to reference it to team?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a team_relationship model at all. A simple belongs_to and has_many relationship wouldn't solve your problem?

Comment: @mdepolli yah you are correct..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The build method wouldn't work. The team was already established, and the user was already established. I just needed to establish the connection. Here's what I have:

Teams Controller:

```
def show
  @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
  @team_members = @team.users
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) if signed_in?
end
```

Join Button Partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :team_id, :value => @team.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Join Team", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but

```
belongs_to :teams
```

should be

```
belongs_to :team
```

Belongs to is always singular.

edit: It looks like you're going for a many to many relationship. Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :team_relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :team_relationships
end

class Team
  has_many :team_relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :team_relationships
end

class TeamRelationship
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: I'm getting "undefined method `team_relationships' for #<User:0x31a6c88>" I'm not sure why this is happening either? I changed it to team, but I can't check if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only has one relation ship you do not need `has_many` , `through`
    as user `belongs_to` only `one` teams ans team has `many` users its  a `has_many` -> `belongs_to` relationship

User Model:

```
belongs_to :team

validates :user_id, presence: true

def team_member?
    team.present?
end

def join!(team)
  return false if team_member?
  team.create!(team_id: team.id)
end  

def unjoin!
  return if team_member?
  team.destroy
end
```

Team model

```
has_many :users

attr_accessible :team_name, :team_id

validates :team_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

default_scope order: 'teams.created_at DESC'
```

TeamRelationship model #NOT NEEDED

_join_team.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Join", join_teams_path(current_user.team_build(team_id: @team_id),  class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", remote: true %>
```

_unjoin_team.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Leave Team", leave_teams_path(current_user.team) , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" , remote: true  %>
```

team_controllor

```
 def join
   @team = Team.find params[:id]
   if current_user.join!(@team.id)
     redirect_to @user #NOTE dont use redirect when you perform actions with ajax.
   else
     #render some error
   end
 end

def leave
  if current_user.unjoin!
     redirect_to @user #NOTE dont use redirect when you perform actions with ajax.
   else
     #render some error
   end
end
```

I suggest to you go through some docs from rails they are well defined

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: That's what I thought, unless we're missing some hidden requirement this isn't a many-to-many association.

Comment: ok I made the changes to the models and I think everything should be good there now. What do I put in the controller/views now to allow a user to create, join, and leave a team? What I have in there is not working (shocking, I know!) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @SteveQ, check the updated answer , modify it as per your req!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Sorry for the slow responses. I'm definitely working on this at night, when I can. Unfortunately it didn't work, I'm getting the below error: 

undefined method `team_build' for #<User:0x3d36218>