# Teams in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I posted on this 1 other time, but it's still not working and despite 3 hours of trying I can't figure out why. I'm new to all this, and this is pretty complicated to me. I'd really really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

I need to create a team of users. A user `belongs_to` a team, a team `has_many` users.

A user should be able to create a team, join an already existing team, unjoin their current team (if you can show me how to make the person who creates the team and make them a team leader that would be great too!)

I have the database tables set up like this:

- Users table: `id, name, email, timestamps, team_id`
- Teams Table: `id, team_name, timestamps, user_id`

ERROR I AM GETTING:

```
undefined method `team_build' for #<User:0x3a14a80>

1: <%= button_to "Join", join_teams_path(current_user.team.build(team_id: @team_id)),    class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :company, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :image
    belongs_to :team, dependent: :destroy

    validates :user_id, presence: true

    def team_member?
       team.present?
    end

    def join!(team)
     return false if team_member?
     team.create!(team_id: team.id)
    end  

   def unjoin!(team)
    return if team_member?
    team.destroy
   end
```

Teams Model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users

attr_accessible :team_name

before_save { |team| team.team_name = team_name.downcase }

validates :team_name, 
        presence: true, 
        length: { maximum: 140 }, 
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

default_scope order: 'teams.created_at DESC'

end
```

Teams Controller:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :signed_in_user

def join
 @team = Team.find params[:id]
  if current_user.join!(@team.id)
   redirect_to @user #NOTE dont use redirect when you perform actions with ajax.
  else
   #render some error
 end
 end

def show
 @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
end

def leave
 if current_user.unjoin!
  redirect_to @user #NOTE dont use redirect when you perform actions with ajax.
 else
   #render some error
 end
end

def new
  @team = Team.new
end

def create
   @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  if @team.save
    flash[:success] = "Team Created!"  
    redirect_to @team
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

 def teams
  @title = "Teams"
  @team = Teams.find(params[:id])
  render 'show_teams'
 end

 def index
Team.all
 end
```

Join button:

```
<%= button_to "Join", join_teams_path(current_user.team.build(team_id: @team_id)),        class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

Unjoin button:

```
<%= button_to "Leave Team", leave_teams_path(current_user.team) , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" , remote: true  %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :teams

match '/teams',          to: 'teams#index'
match '/new_team',       to: 'teams#new'
```

Comment: Is your route configuration working? If yes, Can you be more specific about the problem you are facing?

Comment: Also are you sure that the relationship is `one-to-many`? or it should be `many-to-many`? because a `user` can subscribe to multiple `teams` and a `team` can have multiple `users`.

Comment: yes, please be a bit more specific about what your issue is. Otherwise, it's hard to tell what exactly the problem might be. looks legit so far so telling us what's wrong will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Teams of users rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134159/teams-of-users-rails-app)

Comment: Why don't you try to create has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between User and Team, and then create a TeamRole model, so if a user creates a team he'll be assigned some role which is in TeamRole for a particular Team, that way a User can have many teams with different roles, or a Team can have many Users with different roles.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include. A user can only belong to ONE team at a time, so I believe that makes it a one-to-many.

Comment: I added the routes.rb file. 

The specific issue I'm getting right now is below:

    undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

    1: <%= button_to "Join",   join_teams_path(current_user.team.build(team_id: @team_id)),  class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

Comment: Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The build method wouldn't work. The team was already established, and the user was already established. I just needed to establish the connection. Here's what I have:

Teams Controller:

```
def show
  @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
  @team_members = @team.users
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) if signed_in?
end
```

Join Button Partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :team_id, :value => @team.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Join Team", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
current_user.teams.build(whatever)
```

is the way you'd do it if you have a has_many relationship. But if you have a belongs_to association, you need:

```
current_user.build_team(whatever)
```

See the  documentation for [belongs_to here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) for more.

Answer (score 1):

"(if you can show me how to make the person who creates the team and make them a team leader that would be great too!)"

For the team leader, you can do it a few ways. Here is a simple way.

```
$ rails generate migration AddTeamLeaderUserIdToTeams team_leader_user_id:integer
$ rake db:migrate
```

What this does is add a new column to your teams table so that each team can store the user id of its team leader (CAUTION: this means that each team can only have one team leader. I can explain if you want how to have multiple team leaders.)

From there, when you create a new team, you can do something like this:

```
team = Team.create({:team_name => "Stanford Cardinal", :team_leader_user_id => current_user.id}).
```

then in the future you can get the team leader as such:

```
team_leader = User.find_by_id(Team.find_by_team_name("Stanford Cardinal").team_leader_user_id))
```

hopes this help a bit. Feel free to ask more questions if something isn't clear.